# Android sms bot

Tags: java, android, sms

I am trying to make a simple android app. When I send sms hi to my mobile from some number, it should reply hi automatically to me in response. And when I send "How are you", it should reply me How are you.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you researched how to access sms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a quick Google search on "How to read and send text messages Android" would really help in this situation as there are plenty of resources available.

Assuming you have the basics of the app already built, look at http://codetheory.in/android-sms/ for more information on how to register to deal with messages as well as receive and send them. There are some direct code examples that you could copy&paste into your code and extend. For instance instead of logging the message, you could simply call a function that you create, to send a message back to that number. Hope this helps!